# How to build an excel form builder?

Tags: excel, forms, builder

I need to build smth to create letters.
I am using mail merge now but there is a problem:
the names, department names, email address, etc are looking great but I also want a list of questions to be in the letter.
Note: I will only be creating 1 letter at a time so my excel will only have the headers row and 1 content row.

Here's the problem. My list of questions look something like this:

1. When did you visit the supermarket?
2. What did you get at the supermarket.
3. Please provide the breakdown of things you got from the supermarket.

*(a table, with 4 columns and 5 empty rows) will try to attach it*

4. Where else did you go afterwards?

---

There will be ard 5 different lists of questions. I hope to use Vlookup to put the list of questions into the mail merge data sheet.

Summary: Problem is the questions part. How to put a huge chunk of contents to mail merge? - The spaces btw the questions are not showing on mail merge, and I cant insert table into 1 excel cell

If there are other ways to build this, please let me know as well.
[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6HKY.png)

Answer (score 0):

Build your own "mail merge" using VBA.

- loop through your list in Excel
- For each: open a word template (which you prepared adding bookmarks)
- Replace the bookmark part with the questions... you can even use a "question template" in word where you copy formatted paragraphs from
- save the populated template as new word file

Comment: I have nvr used VBA before, but Im willing to learn. Those VBA basics youtube videos, do they teach the things needed for this case (the skills to do the mail merge VBA)?

Comment: I am afraid, my suggestion needs advanced VBA skills as you need to interact with another application and use word VBA as well... Maybe you could use 5 different word templates with the 5 sets of questions and use VBA only to select the right template for the mail merge?

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I just started learning the basics of VBA. Can I check if learning excel VBA is correct? Because I just found out that microsoft words also have VBA.

Comment: Excel and word VBA are very similar - just the object model is different.. But for your task you need both and frankly spoken : If you are new to VBA I would not advise to start with a problem that combines Excel and word